# check the equality of two ideals in Singular http://www.singular.uni-kl.de 

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

How one can check in Singlar that two ideals are equal? For example in macaulay 2, it is enough to write I==J, and then we will get True or False...

Comment: Read the manual?

Comment: Also, on the website you give in the title you will find a link to a forum specifically dedicated to Singular.
In general I consider basic question on the usage of specific software as off-topic for MO (specialized ones and question about software are something else).   



